# Spark SQL result different from Hive SQL result

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I performed the SQL statement, `select cityroaddis from trip_db.tripTable where tripid='a0001' and day>'2020-09-09'`, in both **hive shell** and **spark shell**, but got totally different results.

The two results

| Hive: cityroaddis | Spark: cityroaddis |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0 | null |

Notice:

- I have specified the data type of `cityroaddis` as Double when creating the hive table
- There is no null value in cityroaddis column in Hive
- Only 0.3% of rows have such problem
- Not all columns have inconsistency between hive and spark (probably 15 out of 70)

Has anybody had such a problem before?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved after I added these two configurations.

```
spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false
spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false
```

---

spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet ： When reading from and writing
to Hive metastore Parquet tables, Spark SQL will try to use its own
Parquet support instead of Hive SerDe for better performance. This
behavior is controlled by the spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet
configuration, and is turned on by default.

spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc: enables new ORC format to
read/write Hive Tables.